# How do I use ImageMagick to convert webp file(s) to jpg in Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) terminal

Tags: image, type-conversion, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a file with the magick command-line tool but I'm confused about what the error means and how to fix it.

I used the following code syntax:

`magick <input>.webp <output>.jpg`

I get this error:

```
magick: delegate failed `'dwebp' -pam '%i' -o '%o'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1911.
magick: unable to open file '/tmp/magick-PGSTH7P1-9rGkrCgVJrwRyuTCjBoRkrJ': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/780.
```

The file I'm converting is in my current directory, and I'm not using a filename for  which is already being used in the directory. I've made sure my spellings are correct, and my file types are correct as well.

There were no errors during installation either:

[Testsuite summary for ImageMagick 7.1.0-40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCxdE.png)

I'm running this on a Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libwebp-dev libwebp6`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for that suggestion. I tried that but I got the error `E: Unable to locate package libwebp6`. I looked online and found that the current version is libwebp7, so I tried `sudo apt install libwebp-dev libwebp7`.
This didn't give any error in installation, but when I tried converting my webp file to jpg file, I received the same error again (the one I wrote in my initial post).

I do want to say that I managed to convert my file via `ffmpeg -i <input>.webp <output>.jpg`

I would still appreciate it if I can find why the magick command isn't working.

Comment: If I run up a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 and do `apt install imagemagick` I get v6.9.11. How come you got v7?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I used the instructions from the [ImageMagick installation from source](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) site.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this again and found I needed:

```
sudo apt install build-essential pkg-config webp libwebp-dev libwebp7
```

Then you need to follow the remainder of the instructions to build from source:

```
./configure
make -j 4

sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: I ran this command and it ran correctly. Afterwards, when I ran the command to convert the webp file to jpg file, I got this:

`Decoded /tmp/magick-LW9dEGPuTiBLGUYew8BV0uIhgbbxUmws. Dimensions: 1280 x 853 . Format: lossy. Now saving...

Saved file /tmp/magick-5OrSywMRV4kDA_8aDQ37BArmz9vTIdGg`

I wasn't able to open the converted image. It showed `unrecognized image file format`.

Comment: So it is all working now?

Comment: It converts, yes, but the converted jpg file doesn't display the image because of some loss during the conversion.

Comment: Try converting your WEBP file to PNG, `magick input.webp output.png` Try also a different WEBP input file.

Comment: What do you mean *"it doesn't display the image"*? What does it display?

Comment: I tried using a different format (.png) to convert the .webp file to, and also chose a different .webp file altogether to try to convert into .jpg or .png, but all I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNZaj.png)

Answer (score -1):

The ffmpeg worked perfectly for me, assuming you have ffmpeg installed, which is the basis of a lot of video players and converter apps. If not:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

on ubuntu and many/most others.
--Bob Harper
I scripted it to fix many webp's at one time...
---shell-code----------------------------------

```
#!/bin/bash
```

for file in *.webp; do

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file/.webp}".jpg
```

done

for file in *.WEBP; do

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file/.WEBP}".jpg
```

done

## ADD more if needed...

```
echo "========================================"
ls -als *.jpg
echo "========================================"
---end-code-------------------------------------
```